# How to properly configure Jenkins to display Jmeter tests?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

guys!

I'm running some jmeter tests on Jenkins, and for some reason it stops displaying the results of the last test run and freezes, only displaying results from a run that has been completed berofe, for example, if I start a new run, it will display the results from a previus one over and over again, no matter how many times I run the test suit... Is it any config that I need to change?

Thanks!

Comment: can you add a screen shot of your job? are you using this plugin? https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance

Comment: Hello, i'm using performance plugin, please, check the other comment I made down below.

Comment: that's not the screen shot i needed. Not sure what you wanted to accomplish. Try this link hopfully you find your answer in it. https://www.baeldung.com/jenkins-and-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the performance plugin... I was analysing it a bit more and I found out that if a test fails once, this failure will be displayed everytime I run a new test and it's displayed as a failed build by jenkins... In the image, the failed test contains two outputs in the http code, 200 which stands for success and 500 which stands for failed (I believe i'm right). [image]

Comment: This is should add to question by using edit, this isn't an answer, also still not clear what is the question